# Adding a unique ID number to a difference of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using this query to find the difference in rows between 2 different databases (A and B) on the same table that I need to insert into B :

```
(select recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype
from A.dbo.relatedrecord
group by recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype)
EXCEPT
(select recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype
from B.dbo.relatedrecord
group by recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype)
```

The problem I'm facing now is that there is a unique id column called RELATEDRECORDID that I need to populate in a sequence (max(B.dbo.relatedrecordid)+1) for each of those result rows.

How can I include this unique ID generation in the original query?

Comment: 1) Why not do SELECT DISTINCT instead of that tricky GROUP BY? 2) Not needed anyway, since you do EXCEPT.

Comment: Why don't you just use `AUTO INCREMENT` on that `ID` column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello AuthenticReplica,

I added a new CTE expression into existing one. You can define [multiple CTE queries](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-multiple-cte-syntax-sql-cte-example-in-sql-server-2008.aspx) in SQL. This second one is only for the max value

Please check below query

```
with cte as (
select * 
from sys.tables
), maxid as (
    select MAX(OBJECT_ID) maxid from sys.tables
)
select 
    rn = maxid + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name), *
from cte
cross join maxid
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [SQL Row_Number() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx) outside the select query. I mean place the two selects in a SQL CTE expression, and in the SELECT list add a new column for Row_Number() with Order By clause which will return a unique number in order for each row

For example you can modify below Select statement

```
;with cte as (

(select recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype
from A.dbo.relatedrecord
group by recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype)
EXCEPT
(select recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype
from B.dbo.relatedrecord
group by recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype)

)
select row_number() over (order by recordkey, class, relatedreckey, relatedrecclass, relatetype) rn, * from cte
```

Comment: Sorry maybe my question wasn't clear, but this is close to what I'm looking for. Your example gives unique sequenced IDs but starting from 1, I need it to start from the current maximum ID in the original table. Could that be done in a similar way?